# Finding general solution to this PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, heat-equation, wave-equation

I need to find all functions $ z = z(y) $ and real constants $ a $ so that $ u(x,y) = z(x+2ay) $ is a solution of the following:

$$
u_{y} = u_{xx} + 4u
$$

So I found that $ z = e^{y} $ satisfies the above PDE but how do I find all the others?

Comment: You have a t variable instead of y in the equation

Comment: If you compute $u_y$, $u_{xx}$ in terms of $z$ and substitute into the equation, you'll get second order ODE  with constant coefficients. Now you can solve for $z=z(y)$.

Comment: Suppose $u(x) = z(x+2ay)$. Then $u_x = z'(x+2ay)$, $u_{xx} = z'(x+2ay)$, $u_y = 2a z'(x+2ay)$ by the chain rule. Hope this helps. $z'(x+2ay)$ denotes the function $z'(y)$ evaluated at the point $x+2ay$.

Comment: Use the chain rule, $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}z(x+2ay) = z''(x+2ay)$. $z$ is a function of $y$ but $z(x+2ay)$ is a function of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: no its $z''(x+2ay)$

Comment: z is a function of y not of x @fGDu94

Comment: And $z=e^y$ is not a solution of the PDE. it should be $z=e^{4y}$

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(z(x+2ay) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x+2ay)z'(x+2ay)$ by the chain rule $ = z'(x+2ay)$

Comment: I think OP mean $z * (x+2ay)$ @fGDu94

Comment: The solution is a lot neater if it is an argument haha

Answer (score 1):

If $\ u(x,y)=z(x+ay)\ $, then
\begin{align}
u_y(x,y)&=az'(z+ay)\ \ \text{ and}\\
u_{xx}(x,y)&=z''(x+ay)\ .
\end{align}
Therefore $\ u\ $ will satisfy the partial differential equation $\ u_y=u_{xx} + 4u\ $ if and only if $\ z\ $ satisfies the ordinary differential equation
$$
z''-az'+4z=0\ .
$$
This differential equation has non-trivial real solutions for any value of $\ a\ $, which can be expressed in terms of the roots, $\ r\ $, of its [charcteristic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_(calculus)), $\ r^2-ar+4=0\ $. These roots are $\ r_1= \frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-16}}{2}\ $ and $\ r_2= \frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-16}}{2}\ $, and the form of the real solutions depends on the nature of them.

- If both roots are the same (i.e. $\ a=\pm4\ $) then the general solution is
  $$
  z(y)=(A+By)e^\frac{ay}{2}\ .
  $$
- If both roots are real, but unequal, (i.e. $\ a^2>16\ $), then the general solution is
  $$
  z(y)=Ae^{\left(\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-16}}{2}\right)y}+B e^{\left(\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-16}}{2}\right)y}\ .
  $$
- If the roots are unequal complex conjugates of each other (i.e. $\ a^2<16\ $) then the general solution is
  $$
  z(y)= e^\frac{ay}{2}\left(A\cos\left(\frac{y\sqrt{16-a^2}}{2}\right)+B \sin\left(\frac{y\sqrt{16-a^2}}{2}\right)\right)\ .
  $$

Where, in every case, $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ are arbitrary real constants. All of the above functions $\ z\ $ will provide you with a solution of the partial differential equation when you put $\ u(x,y)=z(x+ay)\ $, and they are the *only* ones that will do so.